# How do i get the ping parameter other than anything in the output?

Tags: bash

I need help to make a ping graph which basically looks like the one on linux, how do i get the ping output?

```
ping -c 1 -i 1 "google.com"
```

I wanted the output like this

```
86 ms
86 ms
97 ms
36 ms
```

I tried using string splitter

Comment: Add output of your ping command to your question (no comment).

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```bash
ping -i 1 "google.com" | awk -F '=' '/time=/ {print $NF}'
```

Which makes output like this

```
PING google.com (142.250.74.46) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from arn09s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.46): icmp_seq=1 ttl=113 time=12.9 ms
64 bytes from arn09s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.46): icmp_seq=2 ttl=113 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from arn09s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.46): icmp_seq=3 ttl=113 time=10.7 ms
64 bytes from arn09s22-in-f14.1e100.net (142.250.74.46): icmp_seq=4 ttl=113 time=11.9 ms
...
```

Into

```
12.9 ms
10.7 ms
10.7 ms
11.9 ms
...
```

The same operation using [`sed`](https://www.gnu.org/software/sed/manual/sed.html#Command_002dLine-Options-1) command would be:

```
ping -i 1 "google.com" | sed -n 's/.*time=//p'
```

Comment: Added sed variant. Because the edit was trivial, not adding it as a separate answer. Also, +1.